# Flutter dropdownButton setState on change not updating dropdown text after selection to show selected item

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

I created a dropdownButton to allow users to select from a dropdown list which will be populated from an API. For now I am populating using a list I created.

Currently the button is displaying the items from my list but after a selection has been made the list doesnt show the selected item and still shows the hint text. What I would like to happen is after a selection has been made then the dropdownButton shows the item that was selected instead of the hint text.

in the onChanged method I added a setState in hopes of updating the _selectedValue variable to the value that was selected and displaying it in the dropdownButton.

I also added a print statement in my setState method and that does trigger and show me the value within the value variable.

Here is my code.

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<int>> listItems = [DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("2016"), value: 2016,), DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("2021"), value: 2021,)];
    int _selectedValue;

body: DropdownButton(
          value: _selectedValue,
          items: listItems,
          hint: Text("Select Year"),
          onChanged: (int value){
           setState(() {
             _selectedValue = value;
             print(value);
           });
          },
        ),
```

Comment: I open new flutter project and tried your code, its working just fine, Maybe you have something else in your code is the problem, that you didn't share with us here

Answer (score 12):

Your code is fine, but the problem is maybe you are initializing the  `_selectedValue` inside the build() method. So that whenever you call set state the widget rebuilds and initialize again with the default value.

```
int _selectedValue;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
    value: _selectedValue,
    items: listItems,
    hint: Text("Select Year"),
    onChanged: (int value){
      setState(() {
      _selectedValue = value;
      print(value);
    });    
},
),
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this issue,  I had the same issue and it was driving me nuts and I was using setState() appropriately etc.,  It was 100% where I was defining the "initialValue" property.

I was defining it right inside the build method. That did not work, even though I had the same setup in  a sister module and it indeed did work.  Not sure why that is.

Once I changed the definition of that variable to the state class, it worked like a charm.  Hope it saves some, some cycles.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).